# Logically setting up trig proofs that are valid when meeting in the middle

Tags: trigonometry

Considering $$2\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos(2x)$$
to show $$8\sin^4(x) = 3 - 4\cos(2x) +\cos(4x)$$
Assuming I did not how to initially do this proof properly, how would I be able to set up a proof that is still valid to show that $$1 = 1$$

The steps were square both sides of $$2\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos(2x)$$, then you get $$2(1 - \cos(2x))^2 = 3 - 4\cos(2x) +\cos(4x)$$
which can lead to $$\cos^2(2x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$$ which is true
Apparently this is not properly valid. My feedback was to put "RTP" before $$2\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos(2x)$$. How can you make a proof that meets in the middle valid?

Comment: If you use \sin and \cos they come out looking nicer.

Comment: Would you please define "meeting in the middle"?

Answer (score 1):

$3 - 4 \cos(2x) + \cos(4x) = 3 - 4 (1 - 2 \sin^2 x) + (2 \cos^2 2x - 1)$

$ = 8 \sin^2 x - 2 + 2 (1 - 2 \sin^2 x)^2 = 8 \sin^4x$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
4\sin^4(x)
&=1-2\cos(2x)+\cos^2(2x)\tag1\\[6pt]
&=1-2\cos(2x)+1-\sin^2(2x)\tag2\\
&=1-2\cos(2x)+1-\frac12+\frac12\cos(4x)\tag3\\
8\sin^4(x)
&=3-4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: square $2\sin^2(x)=1-\cos(2x)$
$(2)$: $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$
$(3)$: apply $\frac12$ of $2\sin^2(x)=1-\cos(2x)$
$(4)$: collect terms on the right and multiply by $2$

Answer (score 0):

$$8\sin^4x=2(1-\cos2x)^2=2-4\cos2x+2\cos^22x=$$
$$=2-4\cos2x+1+\cos4x=3-4\cos2x+\cos4x.$$
If really want to use $2\sin^2x=1-\cos2x$ only, we obtain:
$$2-4\cos2x+2\cos^22x=2-4\cos2x+2-2\sin^22x=$$
$$=4-4\cos2x-1+\cos4x=3-4\cos2x+\cos4x.$$